Echarts visualMap issue with series-line
I setup a chart with visualMap color, it color only the items not the line.
Anyone understand what happens ?

Here the project: Echarts sandbox
or here: Echarts codepen

It seems that echarts doesnt color the line if the depicted visualmap dimension is not an axis dimension. Which makes sense because it cant tell where the breaking point, from one piece to another along the line, is. Since the markings in your plot suggest that the coloring is dependant on the yAxis value you could change the visual map dimension to the yAxis dimension.
Here is a reduced example:
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    scale: true
  },
  visualMap: [
    {
      type: 'piecewise',
      show: false,
      dimension: 4,
      pieces: [
        {
          label: 'blue',
          max: 1445,
          color: '#0d92ea',
        },
        {
          label: 'green',
          min: 1445.0001,
          max: 1455,
          color: '#11b84e'
        },
        {
          label: 'yellow',
          min: 1455.0001,
          max: 1465,
          color: '#ffc800'
        },
        {
          label: 'red',
          min: 1465.0001,
          color: 'red'
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        ['1', '66', '2022-06-14T07:19:03', 'AUTOMATIC', 1455.95, 3],
        ['2', '0', '2022-06-15T07:19:03', null, 1456.355, 3],
        ['4', '0', '2022-06-17T07:19:03', null, 1457.165, 3],
        ['6', '0', '2022-06-19T07:19:03', null, 1457.975, 3],
        ['7', '0', '2022-06-20T07:19:03', null, 1458.38, 3],
        ['8', '0', '2022-06-21T07:19:03', null, 1458.785, 3],
        ['9', '0', '2022-06-22T07:19:03', null, 1459.19, 3],
        ['11', '1861', '2022-06-24T20:00:00', 'NORECOVERY', 1460, 3],
        ['0', '0', '2022-07-18T22:00:00', null, null, 4],
        ['36', '1858', '2022-07-19T22:00:00', 'MANUAL', 1440, 1],
        ['37', '0', '2022-07-20T22:00:00', null, 1440.121, 1],
        ['38', '0', '2022-07-21T22:00:00', null, 1440.242, 1],
        ['40', '0', '2022-07-23T22:00:00', null, 1440.485, 1],
        ['41', '0', '2022-07-24T22:00:00', null, 1440.606, 1],
        ['42', '0', '2022-07-25T22:00:00', null, 1440.727, 1],
        ['43', '0', '2022-07-26T22:00:00', null, 1440.848, 1],
        ['44', '0', '2022-07-27T22:00:00', null, 1440.97, 1],
        ['47', '0', '2022-07-30T22:00:00', null, 1441.333, 1],
        ['48', '0', '2022-07-31T22:00:00', null, 1441.455, 1],
        ['49', '0', '2022-08-01T22:00:00', null, 1441.576, 1],
        ['50', '0', '2022-08-02T22:00:00', null, 1441.697, 1],

        ['53', '0', '2022-08-05T22:00:00', null, 1442.061, 1],
        ['54', '0', '2022-08-06T22:00:00', null, 1442.182, 1],
        ['55', '0', '2022-08-07T22:00:00', null, 1442.303, 1],
        ['56', '0', '2022-08-08T22:00:00', null, 1442.424, 1],
        ['58', '0', '2022-08-10T22:00:00', null, 1442.667, 1],
        ['59', '0', '2022-08-11T22:00:00', null, 1442.788, 1],
        ['60', '0', '2022-08-12T22:00:00', null, 1442.909, 1],
        ['61', '0', '2022-08-13T22:00:00', null, 1443.03, 1],
        ['63', '0', '2022-08-15T22:00:00', null, 1443.273, 1],
        ['64', '0', '2022-08-16T22:00:00', null, 1443.394, 1],
        ['65', '0', '2022-08-17T22:00:00', null, 1443.515, 1],
        ['66', '0', '2022-08-18T22:00:00', null, 1443.636, 1],
        ['67', '0', '2022-08-19T22:00:00', null, 1443.758, 1],
        ['69', '1859', '2022-08-21T18:00:00', 'NORECOVERY', 1444, 1],
        ['70', '0', '2022-08-22T18:00:00', null, 1445.375, 2],
        ['71', '0', '2022-08-23T18:00:00', null, 1446.75, 2],
        ['72', '0', '2022-08-24T18:00:00', null, 1448.125, 2],
        ['73', '0', '2022-08-25T18:00:00', null, 1449.5, 2],
        ['74', '0', '2022-08-26T18:00:00', null, 1450.875, 3],
        ['76', '0', '2022-08-28T18:00:00', null, 1453.625, 3],
        ['77', '1860', '2022-08-29T22:00:00', 'NORECOVERY', 1455, 3],
        ['0', '0', '2022-09-03T22:00:00', null, null, 3],
        ['83', '1862', '2022-09-04T22:00:00', 'MANUAL', 1440, 1],
        ['84', '0', '2022-09-05T22:00:00', null, 1440.2, 1],
        ['85', '0', '2022-09-06T22:00:00', null, 1440.4, 1],
        ['86', '0', '2022-09-07T22:00:00', null, 1440.6, 1],
        ['87', '0', '2022-09-08T22:00:00', null, 1440.8, 1],
        ['89', '0', '2022-09-10T22:00:00', null, 1441.2, 1],
        ['91', '0', '2022-09-12T22:00:00', null, 1441.6, 1],
        ['93', '1863', '2022-09-14T22:00:00', 'NORECOVERY', 1442, 1],
        ['94', '0', '2022-09-15T22:00:00', null, 1442.4, 1],
        ['95', '0', '2022-09-16T22:00:00', null, 1442.8, 1],
        ['96', '0', '2022-09-17T22:00:00', null, 1443.2, 1],
        ['97', '0', '2022-09-18T22:00:00', null, 1443.6, 1],
        ['98', '0', '2022-09-19T22:00:00', null, 1444, 1],
        ['99', '0', '2022-09-20T22:00:00', null, 1444.4, 1],
        ['100', '0', '2022-09-21T22:00:00', null, 1444.8, 1],
        ['102', '0', '2022-09-23T22:00:00', null, 1445.6, 2],
        ['103', '1864', '2022-09-24T22:00:00', 'NORECOVERY', 1446, 2]
      ],
      encode: {
        x: 2,
        y: 4
      },
    }
  ],
};



yeah it looks logic, I could too use X Axis dimension in time mode or convert time in int millisecondes (convert it in time with formatter) and use it in visualMap. Thanks Matthias
